# Poor graphics performance/quality - GeForce GT710 2GB + Nouveau drivers (18.04)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nouveau

I have recently installed Ubuntu Desktop on my Ubuntu 18.04 server (previously no X).

Using the default Nouveau drivers I am experiencing extremely poor quality graphics (e.g. photos on websites) and animation performance seems poor.

Given that the graphics card is relatively powerful for normal usage, and the system is high spec (Ryzen 5 3600, 32GB DDR3000 RAM, 500GB NVMe) I think this must be a driver/config issue.

I did try using the NVIDIA propriety drivers but also had problems with those, including my desktop having a strong green tint, which is why I ended up going back to Nouveau.

How can I fix this? Ideally I would like to avoid the NVIDIA drivers and somehow configure the Nouveau ones correctly, if this is possible.

Comment: Ask in the right place: https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/

Very unlikely to get such specific support here.